# Local-to-global inequalities for measures: Brunn-Minkowski, Ahlswede-Daykin, what else?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, big-list, inequalities

This question is motivated by an obvious formal analogy between two well-known inequalities:

> **Log-concavity and Brunn-Minkowski inequality**
>
> Let $\mu(dx) := m(x) dx$ be an absolutely continuous measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$, such that its density $m$ is log-concave, i.e. for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^d, \lambda \in [0,1]$ $$m(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) \ge (m(x))^\lambda (m(y))^{1-\lambda}$$
>   Then for all measurable $X,Y \subset \mathbb{R}^d, \lambda \in [0,1]$ $$\mu(\lambda X + (1-\lambda) Y) \ge (\mu(X))^\lambda (\mu(Y))^{1-\lambda}$$
>   where $X$ and $Y$ are measurable, and $\lambda X + (1-\lambda) Y$ is a properly defined measurable version of $\{\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y \mid x \in X, y \in Y\}$.

Note that the pointwise inequality for densities may be thought of as the Brunn-Minkowski inequality for, say, small enough balls - which might be a way to get rid of the reference Lebesgue measure in the statement.

> **Log-supermodularity and Ahlswede-Daykin inequality**
>
> Let $L$ be a finite or countable distributive lattice, and let $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_4$ be measures on $L$, such that for all $x,y \in L$ $$ \mu_1\{x \wedge y\} \mu_2\{x \vee y\} \ge \mu_3\{x\} \mu_4\{y\}$$
>   Then for all $X, Y \subset L$ $$ \mu_1(X \wedge Y) \mu_2(X \vee Y) \ge \mu_3(X) \mu_4(Y) $$

So here is the question: what are the other examples of inequalities that share a similar structure? A more precise question may be: what are other classes of $n$-ary operations $f_1,\dots,f_k$ on some space $S$, such that for some fixed $\lambda_i, \kappa_j \ge 0$, $\sum_i \lambda_i = \sum_j \kappa_j$ an inequality $$(\mu(Y_1))^{\lambda_1} \dots (\mu(Y_k))^{\lambda_k} \ge (\mu(X_1))^{\kappa_1} \dots (\mu(X_n))^{\kappa_n},$$ $$Y_i := f_i(X_1,\dots,X_n), X_j \subset S$$ follows from an "infinitesimal version" of itself - i.e. for sets that are in an appropriate sense "small enough"?

P.S. As I just learned from Wikipedia, Ahlswede-Daykin inequality has a nice generalization to $2k$ measures, due independently to [Aharoni & Keich](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X%2894%2900294-S) and [Rinott & Saks](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01202353) that fits into the same framework.

Answer (score 4):

The question is a little vague, but you will find a lot of inequalities "that share a similar structure" to the Brunn–Minkowki inequality (or Prekopa–Leindler inequality) in the survey [Barthe - The Brunn–Minkowski theorem and related geometric and functional inequalities](http://www.icm2006.org/proceedings/Vol_II/contents/ICM_Vol_2_72.pdf) in the [ICM 2006 proceedings](http://icm2006.org/proceedings/vol2.html).

Answer (score 1):

In the preprint [Mixed volume and an extension of intersection theory of divisors](http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.0433), Kaveh and Khovanskii define an intersection index for an $n$-tuple of finite-dimensional spaces of rational functions on an irreducible $n$-dimensional complex algebraic variety. Among the properties of the intersection index they prove, there is an analog of Alexandrov–Fenchel inequality (Theorem 4.28 and Corollary 4.29).